# Run Multiple bash commands and return false if one of them fails in bash

Tags: bash, rspec

I am setting up a script that will execute a series of bundle exec rspec commands and I want it to return false if any of them fail. But I still want it to run all the tests. Is there a shorter way to accomplish this without a bunch of if or test statements?

Comment: what do you have so far? only thing I can think of is have in a array all the return codes `$?` and at the end of the script loop through and if any return code is not equal to 0 set a boolean to false and break and exit the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it currently like this, but I'll update the answer with nicer syntax if I'm able to write a bash function to handle this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set +x

RETVAL=0

command1 || RETVAL=1
command2 || RETVAL=1
command3 || RETVAL=1

exit $RETVAL
```

Answer (score -1):

Track their exit code in a variable, and exit with it.  I added the line number to for troubleshooting what broke.

```
declare -i r_code=0    # return code
command1 || { r_code+=$?; echo "ERROR at $LINENO
}

command2 || { r_code+=$?; echo "ERROR at $LINENO
}

exit $r_code
```

Comment: @jgr208 not exactly true-- if all the commands are functions  that log your errors, you have all the info you need.  The OP asked for exiting with failures, not to design the whole script for him, which can't be done w/o more info.

Answer (score -1):

This is a for loop that will go through all the return codes and if one failed will exit with the first seen failed return code.

```
i=0
rc=0
command1 
rcode[i]=$?
i=i+1
command2
rcode[i]=$? ... n
for i in "${rcode}"
do
   if [ $i -ne 0 ]; then
      rc=$i
      break
   fi
done
exit $rc
```